# woocommerce breadcrump missing shop link

Tags: theme-development, plugins

I have a WordPress site that uses courtur theme with woocommerce I didn't install the site so i'm not sure if it was configured correctly.
my URL structure for product-category page as follow:

mysite/shopping/

and my product page url:

Mysite/product-category/category_name/

my category page breadcrump show as follow:

You are here: **Home**

my category page breadcrump show as follow:

You are here: **Home**
I need to make it show as : You are here: Home / shop/ category_name

my product page breadcrump :
You are here: **Home/blog/product**
where blog links to my shop page !!
I need to make it show as : You are here: Home / shop/ category_name / product_name

I checked permalinks options but it seems OK . I checked breadcrumb.php template file it seems that it consider that shop () page is the home page of my site.

How can I fix this , should i edit breadcrumb.php or there is an error in my settings? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done a lot easier. It is just necessary to change the permalinks settings accordingly - as mentioned on github at the [issue 3145](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/3145#issuecomment-18552561):

> Meet this criteria:
>
> ```
> // If permalinks contain the shop page in the URI prepend the breadcrumb with shop 
> if (
>   $shop_page_id
>   && strstr( $permalinks['product_base'], '/' . $shop_page->post_name )
>   && get_option( 'page_on_front' ) !== $shop_page_id
>  ) {
>    $prepend = $before 
>      . '<a href="' . get_permalink( $shop_page ) . '">' 
>      . $shop_page->post_title . '</a> ' 
>      . $after . $delimiter;
>  }
> ```
>
> Otherwise its never prepended.

To apply this one has to go to:

> → WordPress Backend → Settings → Permalinks

And set the woocommerce permalinks settings to one of these:

- Shop Base
- Shop Base With Category
- Custom Base

If the latter is used the slug »/shop/...« has to be prepended.

There is an [issue 6584](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/6584):

> Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 't' in wc-core-functions.php on line 533

Which for example occures if the »Custom Base« looks like this: »/shop/product/...«. There is a [commit](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/commit/4d3fbaa9e07e82939ec7e25b41237af672ab0d99) that fixed it, which is available in master, but not 2.2.8.

The slug part shop can be replaced by something else too, for example something localized.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that breadcrumb code was in header.php of my courture theme folder and author of that theme didn't write code for products or product category pages so I added

```
elseif (is_single() && get_post_type() == 'product'){   
$posts_page_id = get_option('page_for_posts');
$posts_page_url = get_permalink($posts_page_id); 
echo '<li>';$bar = "shopping";
if(get_option_tree('blog_name', '', false))
/*$bar=get_option_tree('blog_name', '', false);*/ 
echo "<a href=".home_url()."/shopping/>$bar</a></li>";
echo "<li>";
the_title();
echo"</li>";
}
```

and for product category page

```
if (is_tax()) { 
$posts_page_id = get_option('page_for_posts');
$posts_page_url = get_permalink($posts_page_id); 
echo '<li>';$bar = "Shopping";
if(get_option_tree('blog_name', '', false)) 
echo "<a href=".home_url()."/shopping/>$bar</a> > </li>" ; 
echo "<li>"; 
woocommerce_page_title(); 
echo"</li>";}
```

I commented the line that get the blog_name because I use custom page for my shop not the woocommerce default one . I don't know if there is another way to do this but I notice that most code in this theme not really professional even in widget css it was a bad choice.